# Android convert string to date

Tags: android

I'm getting date from JSON Response in string format , but right now i want to that staring date into date format. How can i convert this **strActiondate﹕ = 9/28/2015 6:52:41 PM** into date , so that i can insert into Sq-lite database.

I have trying this way

```
strActiondate = jobjVessels.getString("actionDate");                

Log.e("strActiondate ", " = " + strActiondate);
try{
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    Date netDate = (new Date(Long.parseLong(strActiondate)));
    Log.e("netDate "," = "+netDate);

}
catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want date in same format = `9/28/2015 6:52:41 PM`

Answer (score 1):

This `DateFormat`: `MM/dd/yyyy`, is not valid for this date:`9/28/2015 6:52:41 PM`.

You need a good [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) that matches this string:

```
a   Am/pm marker        Text    PM
H   Hour in day (0-23)  Number  0
m   Minute in hour      Number  30
s   Second in minute    Number  55
```

So this:

```
String strActiondate = "9/28/2015 6:52:41 PM"; 
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
Date netDate = sdf.parse(strActiondate);
System.out.println(netDate);
```

Will output:

```
Mon Sep 28 06:52:41 CEST 2015
```

In your code:

```
try{
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
    Date netDate = sdf.parse(strActiondate);       
    Log.d("netDate "," = "+netDate);  // log.e is an error... so better d or i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
strActiondate = jobjVessels.getString("actionDate");

Log.e("strActiondate ", " = " + strActiondate);
try{
     DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
     Date netDate = sdf.parse(strActiondate);
     Log.e("netDate "," = "+netDate);
 }
 catch(Exception ex){
     ex.printStackTrace();
 }
```